# beamer: \nameref calls the name of the section instead of the name of the theorem environment

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, theorems

In my LaTeX documents, I am playing with a lot of axioms which I write under a `theorem` environment, while using the following math packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

I define the `axiom` environment in the preamble,

```
\newtheorem{ax}{Fairness axiom}
```

then in the text I write,

```
\begin{ax}[name of the axiom]
\label{label of the axiom}
{definition of the axiom}
\end{ax}
```

To refer to these axioms, I use `\nameref{label of the axiom}` through the following packages

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
```

In the `article` document class, `\nameref{label of the axiom}` does exactly what I want: It references the *name* of the axiom with a hyperlink to its definition.

But in the `beamer` class, `\nameref{label of the axiom}` instead references the name of the *section* in which the axiom is included.

Do you know why? Is there any way to make the `beamer` class behave like the `article` class in this matter?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)

Comment: Do things work if you insert a `\phantomsection` command immediately prior to the axiom environment?

Comment: No, unfortunately phantom section does not change anything :-s

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Class `beamer` stores the theorem name in `\inserttheoremaddition`. That needs to be passed at the right time to `nameref`:

```
\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
  \expandafter\NR@gettitle\expandafter{\inserttheoremaddition}%
}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Wonderful, adding this code to the preamble makes it work just fine! Many thanks

Comment: @user21434 I have also added this to the next versions of `nameref` (2.43) and `zref-titleref` (3.0).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek can you see easily whether something similar is needed for `\nameref` on slide names? I tried this `\addtobeamertemplate` with `frame begin` and `\insertframetitle` with no effect. If you prefer, I can also create an MWE, but if it is a straightforward fix...

Comment: On second thought, I figured you'd probably want an MWE, so here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/567052/23992. Your time would be much appreciated!