# How to get \nameref working on beamer slide titles?

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, slideshow, nameref

`\nameref` and `beamer` sometimes need some work to play nicely together. In the below MWE, I would want the text to say "`\nameref` uses the frame title.", but it says "`\nameref` uses the section title."

I have tried adding this, by analogy with [theorem titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79285/23992), but with no effect:

```tex
\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{frame begin}{%
  \expandafter\NR@gettitle\expandafter{\insertframetitle}%
}{}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\section{the section title}
\begin{frame}[label=l]{the frame title}
    \texttt{\textbackslash nameref} on a frame uses \nameref{l}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(In case you're wondering why I need the slide title: I'm using `beamerarticle` to also create a handout, and `xr` for external references. In the handout, I want to be able to refer to "Slide 3 (Title)".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label in a beamer frame is set before the title is processed (in the `beamer@frameslide` environment in `beamerbaseframe.sty`). This makes it difficult to combine the two actions, i.e., set the name for `\nameref` and set the label.

One workaround is to set an additional label during the title processing. One macro that exposes the title is `\beamer@inlineframetitle`, so that is a candidate for patching with the `etoolbox` package. To avoid defining a duplicate label you can use a prefix for the new label, for example `nr`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\beamer@inlineframetitle}{%
\GetTitleString{#1}\let\@currentlabelname\GetTitleStringResult%
\label{nr\beamer@againname}}%
{\typeout{patch ok}}{\typeout{patch failed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{the section title}
\begin{frame}[label=l]{the frame title}
    Original nameref: \nameref{l}
    
    Extra nameref: \nameref{nrl}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

To improve on this solution you could try to patch `beamer@frameslide` to defer the label to a later point where the title is available, in order to use the original label, or vice versa try to expose the title earlier in this environment. Modifying Beamer in this way is not easy however, so maybe the workaround given here would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely sufficient for my purposes. I made a small change: I now use `\ifdefempty{\beamer@againname}{}{\label{nr\beamer@againname}}` to avoid duplicate labels `nr` for slides without label.